# Mingw and Eclipse unable to find library

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw, static-libraries

I'm having the issues simlar to what's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127623/mingw-eclipse-ld-exe-does-not-find-libraries). I created a new project, added the library path in Eclipse and added the name of the library to use. But the MingW linker can't find the library. I've tried using "/" instead of "\" (this was the solution to the issue Iiked to), as well as several other things, but no luck. Couldn't find anything that worked in the mingw documentation.

My command is as follows:

```
g++ -LD:/ocv/build/x86/mingw/lib -o OCVTest.exe "src\\OCVTest.o" -ltest.a 
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ltest.a
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The file is called test.a

In command line I tried using

```
g++ -L"D:/ocv/build/x86/mingw/lib" -o OCVTest.exe "src\\OCVTest.o" -ltest.a
```

But this didn't help either.

I installed MingW and Make for Windows. I added both of those to my PATH variable.

Comment: name it `libtest.a` and use `-ltest` option to g++

Comment: @zaufi: You're right. Doing that eliminated the issue. I am guessing I had multiple issues. Please post it as answer so I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

name it libtest.a and use -ltest option to g++.
static libs in *nix (include mingw) supposed to be named like `libxxx.a`, `-l` option tells to compiler to find libraries in specified paths (current and given via `-L` option(s)). but to link w/ static lib one may give a fullname (w/o any option)... just pass libtest.a