# Mingw and Eclipse unable to find library - 2

Tags: c, eclipse, mingw, static-libraries, opus

I am faced with the exact same situation as the question raised by Gustavo in the following [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14533855/mingw-and-eclipse-unable-to-find-library). Also, I have tried all the solutions posted in that link and other tags (such as changing library names from opus.a to libopus.a, change '\' to '/' and so on) but none of these have solved my problem. By opening the properties of the library file, these are the following things displayed:

**Path:** /demo/opusfile/libopusfile.a

**Type**: File (Static Library)

**Location**: U:\data\Jag\eclipse\wrksp\demo\opusfile\libopusfile.a

The error message displayed by Mingw is as follows:

```
15:56:57 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project demo ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
gcc -o demo.exe "src\\demo.o" -lU:/data/Jag/eclipse/wrksp/demo/opusfile/libopusfile.a 
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lU:/data/Jag/eclipse/wrksp/demo/opusfile/libopusfile.a
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Could someone please let me know what am I missing ? I am not able to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution, thanks to the answer posted in this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031290/gcc-ld-cannot-find-link-library). So basically to summarize the solution, I had to remove the 'lib' prefix, the '.a' suffix and the library path when I specified the libraries (-l parameters). The library path has to be specified in the -L parameter . This resolved the above problem but led to another hurdle by Mingw:

```
libopusfile.dll.a: could not read symbols: Archive has no index; run ranlib to add one.
```

I executed the 'ranlib' command in the command prompt

```
cmd_path> ranlib libopusfile.dll.a
```

, as suggested by the compiler, and this solved all my issues!